# 'Login' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss

I am creating a login form in react using Typescript. I have set props type as any. But i cannot import it into App file. It is returning error as **'Login' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element.** I have used JSS as stylesheet. It is actually a typescript error.
What am i doing wrong here? Can someone point it out??

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { createUseStyles } from "react-jss";
import logo from "../../assets/logo.png";
const useStyles = createUseStyles({
    wrapper: {
        margin: "0",
        padding: "0",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: "100vh",
        backgroundColor: "#d0d0d0",
    },
    headline: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#d0d0d0",
    },
    loginForm: {
        width: "400px",
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        padding: "20px",
        borderRadius: "10px",
    },
    form: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    label: {
        margin: "10px",
        fontSize: "20px",
        fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    username: {
        width: "90%",
        padding: "10px",
        margin: "10px",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        border: "1px solid #d0d0d0",
    },
    primary: {
        width: "90%",
        padding: "10px",
        margin: "10px",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        border: "1px solid #d0d0d0",
        backgroundColor: "#00a8ff",
        color: "#fff",
        fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    paragraph: {
        margin: "5px",
        fontSize: "16px",
        fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    logo: {
        width: "100px",
        height: "60px",
        alignSelf: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
    },
    support: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        color: "#717171",
        fontSize: "12px",
    },
});

const Login = (type: any) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [user, setuser] = useState({
        fullname: "",
        email: "",
        username: "",
        password: "",
        retypepassword: "",
    });

    const handleClick = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Successful");
    };

    const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setuser({
            ...user,
            [name]: value
        })

        return (
            <div className={classes.wrapper}>
                {console.log("User", user)}
                <div className={classes.headline}>
                    <img src={logo} alt="logo" className={classes.logo} />
                    <h1>St. Lawrence Library Management System</h1>

                </div>
                <div className={classes.loginForm}>
                    <form className={classes.form}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="username" className={classes.label}>
                                Username
                            </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="username"
                                className={classes.username}
                                value={user.username}
                                placeholder="Enter username"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            <label htmlFor="password" className={classes.label}>
                                Password
                            </label>
                            <input
                                type="password"
                                name="password"
                                className={classes.username}
                                value={user.password}
                                placeholder="Enter password"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button className={classes.primary} onClick={handleClick}>
                            Login
                        </button>
                        <p className={classes.paragraph}>Want to add another admin?</p>
                        <button className={classes.primary}>
                            Add Admin
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.support}>
                    <p>Supported by St. Lawrence College</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: You seem to have bundled your component's `return` inside the `handleChange` function

Comment: Yep. Appear to be missing a brace.

Comment: @Phil Thanks man. I have actually misplaced closing bracket of handleChange.